# How to change tab size using css?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

I am building my own website. I have three tabs set up with the code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-justified" role="tablist">
    <li class="active"><a href="#contact-info" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Contact Info</a></li>
    <li><a href="#personal-info" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Personal Info</a></li>
    <li><a href="#skin" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Skin Condition</a></li>
```

Personal info and Skin Condition all for two rows of text, however Contact Info only forms one. This is causing Contact Info to have a different button size. How can I use CSS to make all of the buttons the same size?

Comment: Please rephrase your question, underline your problems and your goals and add some CSS and a jsFiddle if possible ...

Comment: If you want Contact Info to appear on two lines? ... you can place a <br/> between the words. Contact<br/>Info

Comment: Nav justified makes all the buttons the same width. Is this going in a narrow column? So many factors come into play, where is this 2 lines? what breakpoint? Do you have a larger font-size on the tabs? The height of the button can be changed or you can make them not wrap, but it's not safe to do so without context.

Answer (score 1):

```
li a{width:150px;display:block}
```

depending on your css you may not need `display:block`, if using `float` for example.

Comment: that didn't do anything. Im assuming I need to give the contact info class an ID. and replace a with the ID name?

Comment: @user3026468 in that case maybe your font is bigger. Try specifying a bigger width, like `width:400px;`